# Use IQueryable on stored procedure in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-4

I'm trying to use `IQueryable` on the stored procedure, the reason for writing a stored procedure is to check multiple conditions in the query. Please correct me if I'm going in a wrong direction.

I assume applying `IQueryable` will be much faster than the `IEnumerable` not to forget I was able to use `IQueryable` on the other entities without any issues.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult CrmBlogGroupType(int? page, bool? Name, bool? AuthorTitle, bool? Description, string search, int? PageSize, string type)
{
    try
    {
        if (type==null)
        {
            type = "A";
        }

        IQueryable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> _objBlogSet = _dataLayer.GetBlogSet(type);
        var Result = _objBlogSet.ToPagedList(page ?? 1, PageSize ?? 10);

        return View(_objBlogSet);
}
```

Data layer:

```
public IQueryable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> GetBlogSet(string type)
{
        IQueryable<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> Obj = _dbContext.Usp_getBlogSetPosts(type).AsQueryable();
         return Obj;
}
```

`Context.cs`:

```
 public virtual ObjectResult<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result> Usp_getBlogSetPosts(string blogSetType)
 {
        var blogSetTypeParameter = blogSetType != null ?
            new ObjectParameter("BlogSetType", blogSetType) :
            new ObjectParameter("BlogSetType", typeof(string));

        return ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.ExecuteFunction<Usp_getBlogSetPosts_Result>("Usp_getBlogSetPosts", blogSetTypeParameter);
}
```

Error:

> The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once

Comment: Now rip out the irrelevant stuff. Like the whole MVC things. Nothing in here is MVC - it all is a pure LINQ & EF query.

Comment: You're thinking is wrong - `IQueryable` only has a benefit if you're building up a query with several `WHERE` components. The benefit is that it's *not yet executed*, and you can add additional `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` expressions, and then at some point later, the built-up query is executed and only those rows matching all your criteria are returned. With a stored procedure, there's no point in doing this - the stored procedure **already** returns a finalized, materialized result set - there's no *deferred execution* model here.

Comment: Hi @marc_s, Thanks for getting me into the right path , Well All that I'm trying to achieve is a speed, coz the stored procedure will return ten thousand records and again i've to perform search on it. Is there any alternative that I can improve the efficiency.
As you can see that i'm using a Pagedlist which will do the paging..

Answer (score 2):

this is because a stored procedure output result set is not of the type IQueryable.. you have to use IEnumerable in case of stored procedures to work